# How to test/check use of NSURLCache?

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

I have added the two lines of code to my project as described in this [blog post](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-network-caching-http-headers).

However, as nothing different happens in the app itself, is there a way to test this behaviour and check it is working as expected? Is there a profile in instruments? Is there something I can print to the log in Xcode when a response is cached/cached response is used?

It just seems so simple to implement, I want to make sure it is actually having an effect on my app and that I won't have to implement a caching system myself.

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: The answer to this heavily depends on what you're actually asking of the URL Loading system. i.e. what APIs are you using in your app for URL loading?

Answer (score 0):

go offline right after you got the page and then reload the web view. the caching should take effect and the page should load I'd think

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure so by analyzing HTTP traffic through a third party software like Charles.

Whenever app will make a request, HTTP Analyzer will pick the request made. If it is using cache, then same will be reflected in it.
(Check the contents of response to confirm the same)