# NSURLCache not being used

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsurlcache

I am attempting to use NSURLCache so that my app will save JSON responses from a web server and not request it so much.

I have added `Cache-Control:Max-Age=604800` to the response headers in the request.

I have added the following code my apps AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //set up the URL cache
    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                             diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
}
```

And my request in the code looks like this:

```
NSString *myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/api/?location=%@,%@&date=%@&method=%@", latitude, longitude, curDate, methodString];

NSLog(@"%@", myURLString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I do not think this is working, because when running with instruments network profile I see a spike in network request each time the view is loaded and if I load the app then put the phone in plane mode no data loads (whereas I suspect it would use the cache).

Is this proof that no cache is being made/used? And, if so, does anyone have any ideas why not? And, if it's not proof, does anyone know how I can better test the caching?

Many thanks.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is not meant to be used for remote URLs. That might be one cause of the problem. I would suggest you repeat your analysis with using `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Ah, that seems to be correct. I will replace with `NSURLConnection`. Thanks.

Comment: repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629214/how-to-test-check-use-of-nsurlcache

Answer (score 0):

`+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` makes absolutely no guarantees about what caching model it will follow. In practice at present, it deliberately ignores any cache.

You should instead use `NSURLConnection` which exposes proper caching controls.